# Why doesn't the login screen show a created New-LocalUser or the Administrator account?

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, windows-11, login, administrator

Login is with a pin code and right clicking on `cmd` allows running in an elevated mode as `Administrator` so that new accounts [can](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/09/18/how-to-add-delete-and-change-local-users-and-groups-with-powershell/) be created:

adding a user:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32>
PS C:\Windows\System32> New-LocalUser

cmdlet New-LocalUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: nicholas
Password: *****************************************

Name     Enabled Description
----     ------- -----------
nicholas True


PS C:\Windows\System32>
PS C:\Windows\System32>
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-LocalUser

Name               Enabled Description
----               ------- -----------
Administrator      False   Built-in account for administering the =
computer/domain
DefaultAccount     False   A user account managed by the system.
defaultuser100001  True
foo                True
Guest              False   Built-in account for guest access to the =
computer/domain
nicholas           True
WDAGUtilityAccount False   A user account managed and used by the system =
for Windows Defender Application Guard scen...


PS C:\Windows\System32>
```

While the Administrator account isn't enabled, the `foo` user can run `cmd` with `Administrator` privileges.  The newly created account shows as enabled yet isn't available from the login-screen as an option.

system info:

```
PS C:\Users\foo>
PS C:\Users\foo> [System.Environment]::OSVersion

Platform ServicePack Version      VersionString
-------- ----------- -------      -------------
 Win32NT             10.0.22621.0 Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22621.0


PS C:\Users\foo>
PS C:\Users\foo>
PS C:\Users\foo> cmd /c ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105]
PS C:\Users\foo>
```

While `Windows 10` is shown above, `winver` shows `Windows 11`:

[image: winver]

the newly created user isn't listed as an option to login.  There are no options, only the single account.

I'm not understanding the finer points distinguishing an account from a profile.  Can I not login as a different user somehow?

---

From IRC, a suggestion from Akik is to run:

```
 FOR %F IN ("%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~*.mum") DO (DISM /Online /NoRestart /Add-Package:"%F")
```

and another suggestion from j​borean93 is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: 10.0.22621.0 always has been Windows 11 22H2

Comment: yes, I'm unclear on the OS.  Adding the `winver` picture now.

Comment: It’s unnecessary. Your running Windows 11 22H2 based on the build your running. Your issue isn’t unique to the version of Windows you’re running. I am guessing the machine is connected to an AD domain?

Comment: I'll have to check for AD domain settings tomorrow.  Quite possibly so.

Comment: Windows 11 Home cannot join an AD domain

Comment: I'm not understanding the pertinance of your question @Ramhound because, if it's Windows 11 Home, which it is, then it cannot join an AD domain by the nature and definition of AD domain's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142334/discussion-between-nicholas-saunders-and-ramhound).

Comment: Did you try to add a user via the GUI yet? what happens if you use the text login prompt can you log in via any user and via the new user?

Comment: I don't know what the text login prompt is.  I have added users through the control panel, yes.  They are not login options.  Just the one account.

Comment: the non-gui login, where you have to enter the username AND the password via the keyboard. Please also add a user through the Windows settings (NOT through the control panel).

Comment: I don't know what the non gui login is...

Answer (score 2):

Your new users need to be a member of the `Users` group.
Here is a simple script I use for creating users

```
param ($Site, $FullName, $UserName, $Password, [switch] $Admin)
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('UserName')) {
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Admin')) {
        $Description = "Admin account for $FullName"
    }
    else {
        $Description = "User account for $FullName"
    }
    if (-Not ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Password'))) {
        $Credential = Get-Credential -UserName $UserName -Message "Supply password for new user"
        $User = New-LocalUser -FullName "$($FullName) - $($Site)" -Name $UserName -Description $Description -PasswordNeverExpires -Password $Credential.Password
    }
    else {
        $User = New-LocalUser -FullName "$($FullName) - $($Site)" -Name $UserName -Description $Description -PasswordNeverExpires -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
    }
    if ($null -ne $User) {
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users"  -Member $User 
        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Admin')) {
            Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $User 
        }
        Write-Output $User
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Usage: $(Split-Path $PSCommandPath -leaf) <Site> <Full Name> <Username> [password] [-Admin]"
}
```

For your situation you could use
`Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users"  -Member "nicholas"`

Comment: A bit more information on your code might be helpful for readers with little experience

Comment: +1 for the code, superb!